# Tokenizing problem Python. How do I tokenize a sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a problem that basically takes as an input for example a sentence like "I like Python"
and after a tokenizing process the output is "I /n like /n Python". This is basically a process/piping Python problem. Thing is is that I think the solution is quite a simple but I cant understand the problem really. The sentences are elements of a tuple. We need to have 3 processes, a source process that basically provides us with the information from the tuple, a transformer process that reads everything that the source process writes in the anonymous pip, it tokenizes it and then writes the result in a FIFO. Lastly, there is the output process which reads everything in the named pipe and it prints it. Imports only os, sys and time modules. This is the code I made but I take I can take suggestions that involve different code as a base.

```py
import os
import sys
import time

MESSAGES = (
    b"I love Python programming",
    b"Inter-process communication is important",
    b"Pipes and FIFOs are used for communication",
)

def source_process(write_pipe):
    try:
        for message in MESSAGES:
            write_pipe.write(message)
            write_pipe.flush()
            time.sleep(1)  # Delay for easy reading
    finally:
        write_pipe.close()

def transformer_process(read_pipe, fifo_path):
    try:
        fifo_fd = os.open(fifo_path, os.O_WRONLY)

        while True:
            message = read_pipe.readline()
            if not message:
                break

            words = message.split()
            transformed_message = b'\n'.join(words)
            try:
                os.write(fifo_fd, transformed_message + b'\n')
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno == 32:  # Broken pipe
                    break
    finally:
        read_pipe.close()
        os.close(fifo_fd)

def output_process(fifo_path):
    try:
        fifo_fd = os.open(fifo_path, os.O_RDONLY)

        while True:
            message = os.read(fifo_fd, 1024)
            if not message:
                break

            print(message.decode(), end='', flush=True)

    finally:
        os.close(fifo_fd)

def main():
    try:
        fifo_path = "my_fifo"
        os.mkfifo(fifo_path)

        source_pipe_read, source_pipe_write = os.pipe()
        transformer_pipe_read, transformer_pipe_write = os.pipe()

        source_pid = os.fork()

        if source_pid == 0:
            os.close(source_pipe_read)
            os.close(transformer_pipe_write)
            source_process(os.fdopen(source_pipe_write, 'wb'))
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            os.close(source_pipe_write)

        transformer_pid = os.fork()

        if transformer_pid == 0:
            os.close(source_pipe_write)
            os.close(transformer_pipe_read)
            transformer_process(os.fdopen(transformer_pipe_write, 'wb'), fifo_path)
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            os.close(transformer_pipe_write)

        output_pid = os.fork()

        if output_pid == 0:
            os.close(transformer_pipe_read)
            output_process(fifo_path)
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            os.close(transformer_pipe_read)

        # Close remaining pipes in the parent process
        os.close(source_pipe_read)
        os.close(transformer_pipe_write)

        # Wait for all child processes to finish
        os.waitpid(source_pid, 0)
        os.waitpid(transformer_pid, 0)
        os.waitpid(output_pid, 0)

    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)

    finally:
        # Remove the named pipe
        try:
            os.unlink(fifo_path)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thx ndclt for editing my code sry I am new to this

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you seem to have figured out a tokenization method that works perfectly for your input- so I'm not sure what to answer here. The way you describe your task - really just "do something simple to demonstrate you get forking, pipes, and FIFOs" - makes me think you've done everything you need to do already.

Comment: Problem is that it doesnt work if you run the program in WSL or in any kind of linux sistem you will see the problems with the output. Thats why i dont get it, I have figured out what piping, FIFO and forking is but i cannot get it to work I dont know why.

Comment: I removed the [tag:unix-ar] tag because I don't see how it relates to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues lie with your pipe logic. Some of your pipes are incorrectly placed, os.fdopen'd with the wrong mode (e.g. a pipe named "write" being opened with a "read" mode), or closed too early.

- Remove the transformer_pipe pipes entirely - they just cause confusion.
- Make sure both of the functions that take a pipe get the correct pipe in the correct mode.
- Be mindful that closing a pipe twice will raise an OSError.

This is hard to reason about and diagnose because...

- Multiple processes sharing the same stderr - so it's difficult to see which process is erroring where and why.
- You have a pipe-pair that is completely unused and just causes confusion (the transformer ones).
- You squelch stack traces in your outer try block and instead just print strings of the exception
- Your main finally block - which deletes the fifo out of the file
  system - is triggered by any of the child forks that don't succeed. This generates red herrings in your program's output.